# Meshes of merged geometries are not properly joined

Tags: three.js, mesh

When I merge geometries, then I export in STL, here is the result of mesh I can finally get:
[image]

As you can see, the join is not well aligned.

If I export same objects from my 3D software, this is what I get and how it would look like:
[image]
Here it is exported as 1 object.

In Threejs, scene is imported from glb.

My code for merged:

```
function mergeGeometries(clone) {
let geoms=[]
let meshes=[]
clone.updateMatrixWorld(true,true)
clone.traverseVisible(e=>e.isMesh && meshes.push(e) && (geoms.push(( e.geometry.index ) ? e.geometry.toNonIndexed() : e.geometry().clone())))
geoms.forEach((g,i)=>g.applyMatrix4(meshes[i].matrixWorld));
let gg = BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries(geoms,true)
gg.applyMatrix4(clone.matrix.clone().invert());
gg.userData.materials = meshes.map(m=>m.material)
gg.scale(10,10,10)

var mergeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(gg, new THREE. MeshLambertMaterial ({color: 0xff0000}));
return mergeMesh
```

}

Is there another way or did I miss something to export a combination of objects as one object in STL or OBJ ?

Comment: Please be a little more specific in the steps you're taking. Writing them out step-by-step could be helpful. I'm asking because you say you're exporting an STL. From where? And where are you opening the STL? Is the STL what has the bleeding geometry? Or is that another effect?

Comment: I suspect your 3D software is merging vertices that are colocated within a particular threshold.  `mergeBufferGeometries` doesn't do that; if the two geometries each have a point at, say (0, 0, 0), then the merged geometry will have two unconnected vertices there.  That's probably why you're seeing the seam in the Three.js merge.

Comment: Indeed, this is probably what’s happen unfortunately